# Adaptive calculations of Wiener filter coefficients

Tags: filters, linear-prediction

Suppose,I have an input of length of lenght 100. data=[x0...x99];
I take a window of lenght 11 from x0 to x10.
windowed data=[x0 x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 x7 x8 x9 x10], 
now, I compute 7 wiener coefficients which are 
[w0 w1 w2 w3 w4 w5 w6];
next I will move by window one sample forward, 
new windowed data= [x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 x7 x8 x9 x10 x11],

My question how can I use the previously calculated wiener coefficients to calculate the new wiener coefficients for the new windowed data? Also I want this to be done in the shortest possible time.

Comment: [Look up Levinson-Durbin.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levinson_recursion)

Comment: Thanks, but i am already using levinson durbin, can i somehow make it more fast ?